# Manipulating web API responses with jQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, import.io

Help please, I am trying to return the value of the key "Book".

```js
var lode = $("#result").load("https://api.import.io/store/connector/3bcafba9-b5f3-4feb-a248-6265c0119606/_query?input=webpage/url:https%3A%2F%2Fwww.packtpub.com%2Fpackt%2Foffers%2Ffree-learning&&_apikey=81c93652057b496d886a97b5465b35816a2e3c29f89aeb50093e05ceef67b1fb244271b5156fdafb31f67b08e9eb8a3b99f12fc06f2d6eb1f86d081e206b852b63487fc7f22be6301831da2dda4142fe").hide;

   // $.parseJSON("lode");
   // $('lode').(payload.results[0].book);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am able to extract the value when the JSON response is hardcoded but the requisite jQuery to programatically return the value still eludes me.
Much thanks 
http://jsbin.com/josuza/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "https://api.import.io/store/connector/3bcafba9-b5f3-4feb-a248-6265c0119606/_query?input=webpage/url:https%3A%2F%2Fwww.packtpub.com%2Fpackt%2Foffers%2Ffree-learning&&_apikey=81c93652057b496d886a97b5465b35816a2e3c29f89aeb50093e05ceef67b1fb244271b5156fdafb31f67b08e9eb8a3b99f12fc06f2d6eb1f86d081e206b852b63487fc7f22be6301831da2dda4142fe";

$('#result').load(url,function(response,status,xhr) {
  $('#result').html($.parseJSON(response).results[0].book);
});
```

you can use this code for getting book value

Comment: Thanks a ton @Onur, so terse and concise. Thanks again.